# How to display data without aggregation in Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-4

I have data that is in the following format:

```
file_name file_size time_stamp
A          100       2014-05-12 12:00
B          200       2014-05-12 12:00
C          300       2014-05-12 12:00
A          50        2014-05-12 12:15
B          45        2014-05-12 12:15
C          600       2014-05-12 12:15
```

How to display data Y-Axis with file size without aggregation (eg A-100,B-200,C3-300 for first 12:00 and A-50,B-45 and C-600 for 12:15)? My data is for each 15 minutes of time interval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try a vertical bar chart with X-Axis aggregation as a date histogram, and then split bars using a Terms sub-aggregation on the `file_name` field.

Since that leaves you with only a single value in each bucket, your Y-Axis agg can be Max, Min or Average, on the `file_size` field.

By also sorting out the ordering on the Terms sub-agg, you should get something like this:

[image: chart]

Comment: works but for huge no of file the windows would be small to display. Marked as answer!

Comment: Please what would the type of file_name be so that it can be aggregatable ? I set a field to text but Can't select it in the list and it shows as aggregatable